# SQL pedidos ultimo trimestre

Tags: sql

como puedo saber los pedidos del ultimo trimestre dado esta pregunta y esta base de datos relacional [image]

-Sería así?

```
SELECT ID_PRODUCTO FROM PRODUCTOS 
    WHERE ID_PRODUCTO IN ( SELECT ID_PRODUCTO FROM PEDIDOS 
                        WHERE FECHA>SYSDATE-90)
```

Como puedo buscarlo sin que me de problemas luego por los meses terminados en 31?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas solo los pedidos, solo los productos o ambos?

Answer (score 2):

La condición del `WHERE` está bien (solo habría que cambiar el '>' por un '>=' ya que sino podrías no considerar algunos casos), solo que estás obteniendo los productos únicamente. En caso de que quieras datos del pedido y el producto deberías unir ambas tablas:

```
SELECT p.ID_PEDIDO, p.CANT, p.FECHA, pr.DESCRIPCION FROM PEDIDOS p # Obtengo id del pedico, cantidad, fecha y descripcion del producto pedido
INNER JOIN PRODUCTOS pr ON pr.ID_PRODUCTO = p.ID_PRODUCTO # Uno las tablas
WHERE p.FECHA >= SYSDATE-90 # Ultimo trimestre
```

Bastará con poner los atributos que necesites en caso de que los del ejemplo sean pocos.

Espero que haya sido de ayuda!

Saludos!